# file attachment issue to email?

Tags: php, email

My file is attached and sent with no error, but the attachment in my Inbox folder shows as follows:

> // this is included in the email subject and body, so not correct
>           file attach boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_xb46dc57fb3a58f8a859f39992cfd954ex"
>       This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
>       // this is included in the email subject and body, so not correct
>       --==Multipart_Boundary_xb46dc57fb3a58f8a859f39992cfd954ex
>       Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
>       Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
>        // this is included in the email subject and body, so not correct
>       test message
>
> ```
> --==Multipart_Boundary_xb46dc57fb3a58f8a859f39992cfd954ex
> Content-Type: image/jpeg;
> name="23.jpg"
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
>
> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/4QC8RXhpZgAASUkqAF4AAAAEABoBBQABAAAAPgAAABsBBQAB
> AAAARgAAACgBAwABAAAAAgAAADEBAgAQAAAATgAAAAAAAABgAAAAAQAAAGAAAAABAAAAUGFpbnQu
> TkVUIHYzLjA4AAUAGgEFAAEAAAA+AAAAGwEFAAEAAABGAAAAKAEDAAEAAAACAAAAMQECABAAAAB
> ```

My sendemail.php code is:

```
<?php

$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers= "From: $_POST[name] <$_POST[email]>";
$headers= $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

/* GET File Variables */ 
            $tmpName = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
            $fileType = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
            $fileName = $_FILES['attachment']['name']; 

            if (file_exists($tmpName)) { 
              /* Reading file ('rb' = read binary)  */

              $file = fopen($tmpName,'rb'); 
              $data = fread($file,filesize($tmpName)); 
              fclose($file); 

              /* a boundary string */
              $randomVal = md5(time()); 
              $mimeBoundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$randomVal}x"; 

              /* Header for File Attachment */
              $headers = "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
              $headers = "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" ;
              $headers = " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; 

              /* Multipart Boundary above message */
              $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
              "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
              "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
              "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
              $message . "\n\n"; 

              /* Encoding file data */
              $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data)); 

              /* Adding attchment-file to message*/
              $message .= "--{$mimeBoundary}\n" . 
              "Content-Type: {$fileType};\n" . 
              " name=\"{$fileName}\"\n" . 
              "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
              $data . "\n\n" . 
              "--{$mimeBoundary}--\n"; 

            } 

            $to_user = "nur_Selam@yahoo.com";    

            $flgchk = mail($to_user, $subject, $message, $headers);     

            //require_once ('./includes/functions_mail.php');

                if ($flgchk) {

                echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"2;url=forwardtoother.php?page=sender.html\">";
                echo "Done, <br>";
                echo "Redirecting you to your <a href=\"?page=sender.html\">Inbox</a>";
                }
                else
                {
                     echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"refresh\" CONTENT=\"2;url=forwardtoother.php?page=sender.html\">";
                echo "Failed to send email, <br>";
                echo "Redirecting you to your <a href=\"?page=sender.html\">Inbox</a>";
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: Use a mailer class like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer to avoid such mistakes and problems.

Comment: I agree with TIMESPLINTER - you're better off with a tried and true package, like PHPMailer, than trying to re-invent the wheel.  But, if you insist on rolling your own MIME encoding, $headers = "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n"; and  $headers = " boundary=\"{$mimeBoundary}\""; should probably be .= not =.